# need code for execution automatically execution

Tags: sas, prompt

does anyone have an idea how to execute a code in SAS at a specific time of day automatically?

some code or a video that serves as a reference and understands how to program it

Comment: It depends a lot on your installation and how SAS is set up. If you'e  and administrator you should have access to the Scheduler. If you're not, you may need to talk to your IT team. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/scheduleug/61559/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n11h7gtnkw4bhbn13ndr66h4wupe.htm

Comment: Otherwise, several options are outlined in these papers: https://www.lexjansen.com/search/searchresults.php?q=scheduling%20jobs

Comment: What SAS product are you using?

Comment: Sas enterprise Guide 8.4